# Powershell Module not automatically loaded for Linux container

Tags: linux, powershell, containers, docker-container

I have a Powershell module that looks like this this:

```
function SayHello
{
    echo "hello"
}
```

I saved it as `say-hello.psm1` and added it to a dockerfile like this:

```
COPY --chmod=0755 say-hello.psm1 /root/.local/share/powershell/Modules/say-hello.psm1
```

When I start the docker image up, and run `SayHello` it tells me that it can't find the command:

[image: SayHello not recognized]

But if I then run an Import-Module command and try it again, it works:

[image: Can work if imported manually]

I thought that maybe I had the wrong folder, but when I run `$Env:PSModulePath` I get `/root/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules`.  According to the documentation, that is where the modules should go.  (I put it in the first one)

**What do I need to do to make my powershell module work without needing to be manually imported?**

Answer (score 5):

I forgot that you need to put the `psm1` file in a folder with the same name as the file (inside the Modules folder).

I did that and it started working just fine.